# PHP mailer error sending e-mail. Hostgator is the e-mail provider

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, mailer

I am stuck with this since a week.
Have tried all combinations available on SO, nothing worked yet.

Here is my function that uses the SMTP send

```
public function Send($Email,$subject,$message){
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        //$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

        $mail->Host = smtp_host_addr; //defined as constant -like mail.example.com
        $mail->Port = smtp_port; //defined as constant tried 465,25,26

        //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

        $mail->Username = Admin_Email; //defined as constant
        $mail->Password = Admin_pwd; //defined as constant
        $mail->AuthType = "LOGIN";
        $mail->setFrom(Admin_Email, 'Admin'); //defined as constant
        $mail->addReplyTo(Admin_Email, 'Admin'); //defined as constant
        $mail->addAddress($Email);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->msgHTML($message);
        //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
        $mail->AltBody = html2text($message); 
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            return false;
            //return $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            //echo "Message sent!";
            return true;
        }

    }
```

It takes a long time to execute sometimes and times out. or comes up with an error saying `PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP connect() failed.` kind off errors.

**The detailed error report is here :**

```
2018-03-01 16:26:17 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2018-03-01 16:27:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2018-03-01 16:28:47 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2018-03-01 16:28:47 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed:
2018-03-01 16:28:47 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A connection failure could be due to a nonexistent host for smtp_host_addr (and constants should be ALL_UPPERCASE in my experience). It might also be due to firewall restrictions. Your hosting provider might ban outgoing email connections or the email server may not be configured to permit connections from your web server.

Comment: @S.Imp I have added the detailed error report to the question. would you please have a check...

Comment: I'm not sure what a successful connection would look like. I suggest either trying to connect to gmail (PHPMailer offers an [example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) on github) and if that works, then you know the problem isn't with your web server. Another approach would be to try different port numbers for your current smtp host.

Comment: @S.Imp Things were fine with g-mail on my local machine. When i hosted it online, the mail was not being sent. So after lot of trobleshooting, i planned to change the mail server to hostgator where i have hosted the site too. That doesn't work either...!

Comment: Can you send the email via gmail when your code is hosted online? If so, then that rules out a problem with your code and suggests you have a problem with the email server or your credentials. If you can't send mail through gmail either when you host online, that suggests that your web server may have a firewall or other restrictions in place.

Comment: @S.Imp now my mails does not work on local too... The mail i got from hostgator with the domain! It's so sick!

Comment: It doesn't look like you're connecting to something that speaks SMTP.

Comment: so, is it an issue with the host address or port? @Synchro

Comment: Can’t tell. It could be an incomplete firewall block by hostgator. Try the telnet & openssl tests from the troubleshooting guide.

Comment: here i have an error while i tried your smtp example... just to ceck tls.  `Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.win.hostgator.com' did not match expected CN=`mail.example.com' [C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\src\SMTP.php line 404] SMTP error: Failed to start encryption: Connection failed. `     I am trying o the local machine... @Synchro

Comment: You do need to set the `Host` property to match the name of your mail server.